# How to do Bluetooth in background in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm trying to listen for my Bluetooth device in the background, but nothing seems to be happening. I tried following this guide here and modifying it for SwiftUI.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

I enabled the `bluetooth-central` background mode.

I opt In to State Preservation and Restoration.

```
let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey : "myCentralManagerIdentifier"]
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
```

I added Restoration Delegate Method. This method gets called when I first run the app again.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {

    guard let peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as? [CBPeripheral] else {
        return
    }
    
    for peripheral in peripherals {
        // ...
    }

}
```

The step for launch options doesn't seem to work for me. The `launchOptions` dictionary is always `nil` for me.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        guard let options = launchOptions else {
            return true
        }
        
        let centralManagerIdentifiers = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals]
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "listen for my Bluetooth device in the background?" That can mean a lot of different things. State Restoration is generally not the most important part of this. For certain problems it's necessary, but it's generally something you add after you have the more basic issues handled. (State Restoration doesn't do anything unless you have some state to restore.) How are you initiating the connection and how do you want it to work?

Comment: Nothing happens when I put the app in the background, and I turn on my bluetooth device. None of my methods are called.

Comment: Have you started a scan or connected to the device before going in the background? I don't see any code in your question that engages with this device. What state do you expect to be restored here? (State Restoration has very little to do with going into the background. It's about relaunching your app when it's been terminated, and providing information back to the app about what state it was previously in so it can setup its connections again. You generally get background access working, and then worry about state restoration for the "fully terminated" case.)

Comment: So when my app is in the foreground as normal, restore state gets called and I automatically connect to the peripheral when didDiscover gets called. When my app goes into the background, and I turn on my bluetooth device nothing gets called.

Comment: It's actively scanning before going into the background. The device I'm working with is only active for a short time before turning off. The user will interact with the Bluetooth device at times when the app is not open.

Comment: How are you starting your scan? (Please show the exact line of code you're using to start it.) Is your scan still in progress when you go into the background?

Comment: (Typically if you want to connect every time the device is turned on, you don't scan for the device. You just connect to it, and wait for it to show up. You should already know the peripheral ID. You can connect to that without re-scanning, and this is normal. A connect request has no timeout. It can run for weeks, even across reboots, and that's normal.)

Comment: So I need to scan to know when the BLE peripheral is turned on. It only stays active for a few minutes before turning off.

Comment: `centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: myServiceUUID, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])`

Comment: Are there any code examples anywhere? I just don't understand what I supposed to do when the app goes into the background in order to discover the BLE device when it's turned on when the app goes into the background.

Comment: "So I need to scan to know when the BLE peripheral is turned on." That's not required or good practice. If you already have a PeripheralID, you should just fetch the CBPeripheral from `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` and then call `connect`. (You should also generally call `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` to make sure the device isn't already connected, which can happen, but this is a somewhat rare edge case.)

Comment: You cannot scan in the background with `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`. It is ignored when you go into the background. If you've already discovered this peripheral since you started the scan, you won't see it again (which is probably the root cause of your symptom).

Comment: So how do I know when this device is turned on when I'm in the background if I'm not able to discover it?

Comment: You call `connect` when you're in the foreground. When the device is turned on (even when you're in the background), the connection will be made by the OS, and your app will be awakened or launched. You don't need to scan for it once you've discovered it once, and you really shouldn't. Connection requests never time out. The key is that you call `connect` while in the foreground.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I was not understanding this aspect of Bluetooth when used with restore state.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer and I can accept? I was not understanding that you just call connect on a restored peripheral and it will connect when the device turns back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you know the device's `peripheralID`, you can fetch a CBPeripheral for it any time using `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)` whether it's connected or not. If it's not connected, you can just call `connect` to start a connection request. There's no need to scan for it once you've seen it before (and this is discouraged, since it's slow and power intensive to scan).

Connection requests never time out. When the app goes into the background, the request will continue. It'll even continue if the app is terminated or the device is rebooted. A connection request can run for weeks. It's totally fine, expected, and battery efficient.

When the device is turned on and in range and connectable, then the OS will handle connecting. It will then either hand control to your app in the background, or launch your app using state restoration. At that point, you can do whatever you want with the connected device.